# Am I right proving Lebesgue measure is inner regular

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

**Lemma**

If $E\subset \mathbb R$ is Lebesgue measurable, then for any given $\epsilon>0$ there exists a closed set $F\subset E$ such that $\mu(E\setminus F)<\epsilon$.

Now I want to prove $\mu(E)=\sup\{\mu(K):K\subset E$ and $K$ is compact $\}$ based on the **Lemma**.

Note: $C$:=$\{\mu(K):K\subset E$ and $K$ is compact $\}$

1. $E$ is bounded, so $\mu(E) < \infty$. $\mu(E)$ is an upper bounder of set $C$, now I want to show it is the least upper bound (i.e. $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists K \subset E$, such that K is compact and $\mu(E) < \mu(K)+\epsilon$).

Based on the **Lemma**, $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists K \subset E$, such that K is compact and $\mu(E\setminus K) < \epsilon$
Since $E$ is bounded, then $K$. Since $\mu(E) < \infty$,we have $\mu(E\setminus K)=\mu(E)-\mu(K)$. $\square$

2. $E$ is unbounded

Let $B(0,k)$ is the open ball center at zero with radius $k$, $A_1=B(0,1), A_n=B(0,n)-B(0,n-1) ,E_n=E \cap A_n$. We can show that $E_n$ is bounded and pairwise disjoint, $E=\cup_{1}^{\infty} E_n $. From case 1, we have $\forall \epsilon>0$, let $\epsilon_n=\frac{\epsilon}{2^{n}}$, $\exists K_n \subset E_n$, such that $K_n$ is compact and $\mu(E_n\setminus K_n) < \epsilon_n$,
so we have $$\mu(E)=\sum \mu(E_n) \leq \sum \mu(K_n)+\epsilon \cdots (\star)$$
Rmk:$K_n$ is pariwise disjoint (Because $E_n$ is pairwise disjoint)

2.1 $\mu(E) < \infty$

Now we have $\sum \mu(K_n) < \infty$ (Because $\sum \mu(E_n) < \infty$). $\sum \mu(K_n)=\lim_{ S \rightarrow \infty} \mu(\cup_{1}^{S}(K_i))$, From $(\star)$, $\exists S'$, such that $\cup_{1}^{S'}(K_i) \subset E,\mu(E) <\mu(\cup_{1}^{S'}(K_i))+\epsilon$. Since $\cup_{1}^{S}(K_i)$ is compact, we have finished the proof.

2.2 $\mu(E) = \infty$

Now we have $\sum \mu(K_n) = \infty$ (Because $\sum m(E_n) = \infty$). So $\forall M>0$, $\exists S'$, such that $\cup_{1}^{S'}(K_i) \subset E,\mu(\cup_{1}^{S'}(K_i))>M$. Since $\cup_{1}^{S}(K_i)$ is compact, $\sup C=\infty$.